# Need suggestion of Apache_beam learning materials for beginners

Tags: apache-beam

I need to learn Apache Beam for a project. I have gone through the 
 Apache Beam documentation and I think this is not enough. Can someone recommend resources to learn Apache Beam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running through the [Python](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/)/[Java](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/) quick start tutorials?

You can also go through an [explanation of the wordcount pipelines](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/), so you'll become more familiar with some of the transforms available in beam.

Once you have a look at the specific wordcount example, you can [dive in the programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/) to get a more detailed understanding of the framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot . This is what I need .